# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Session::getId() in /home/****/public_html/***/catalog/controller/common/header.php on line 82

Tags: opencart

I am using opencart 1.5.6 and my admin section working fine. I am getting this issue on front-end (Home Page)

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Session::getId() in /home/***/public_html/***/catalog/controller/common/header.php on line 82

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Check your server settings, reinstall OC, etc.